# How to get minimum and maximum values of a Check Constraint using TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using following script to create a check constraint if it does not exist :

```
if not exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id= object_id(N'[APA].[CK_APALog_APALogType_Range]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id,N'IsConstraint')=1)
    ALTER TABLE [APA].[APALog] ADD CONSTRAINT CK_APALog_APALogType_Range CHECK ( APALogType >=1  AND APALogType <=3 )
go
```

and  with the following query retreiveing some information I need about the constraint :

```
select  constraintsColumns.COLUMN_NAME ,tableConstraints.CONSTRAINT_NAME ,tableConstraints.CONSTRAINT_TYPE ,tableConstraints.TABLE_NAME 
from information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tableConstraints  
join information_schema.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE constraintsColumns  
     on   tableConstraints.TABLE_NAME=constraintsColumns.TABLE_NAME  
     and  tableConstraints.CONSTRAINT_NAME =constraintsColumns.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
where tableConstraints.CONSTRAINT_TYPE in ('CHECK') and constraintsColumns.COLUMN_NAME='APALogType'
```

what I can not achieve is to retreive `minimum` and `maximum` values I have specified in constraint creation .

Is this possible to retreive these values using `TSQL` ?

Comment: I think you would have to parse the constraint definition.  SQL Server doesn't "know" there are minimum and maximum values.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff How could the expression be retrieved and parsed in tsql then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have to resort to parsing it out of the text; though at least the text is normalized, which makes it a bit easier:

```
DECLARE @text nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @text = CHECK_CLAUSE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'CK_APALog_APALogType_Range' AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'APA'

DECLARE @nClose int

DECLARE @nGreaterThan int = PATINDEX('%>=([0-9]%', @text) + 3 --Add 3 for the >=(
SET @nClose = CHARINDEX(')', @text, @nGreaterThan)
DECLARE @min int = CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@text, @nGreaterThan, @nClose - @nGreaterThan))
PRINT 'Min = ' + CONVERT(varchar, @min)

DECLARE @nLessThan int = PATINDEX('%<=([0-9]%', @text) + 3 --Add 2 for the <=(
SET @nClose = CHARINDEX(')', @text, @nLessThan)
DECLARE @max int = CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@text, @nLessThan, @nClose - @nLessThan))
PRINT 'Max = ' + CONVERT(varchar, @max)
```

Comment: thx , I tried it has the following error : Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '[APALogType]>=(1)' to data type int.

Comment: @Karamafrooz - ah right; after I talked about the normalization - I didn't actually check what it normalizes *to*! It wraps the values in parentheses - code updated.